# Como colocar texto embaixo do BoxDecoration Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá!

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma lista que mostra as pessoas online, com seu nome em baixo. Só que eu consegui fazer o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de colocar um nome em baixo da imagem da pessoa. Não consegui encontrar como posso fazer, e tentei colocar um `child: Text()` pro container, mas não deu certo.

Meu código está assim:

```
Widget _listOnline() {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35),
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/Rubio_Circle.png"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta que você utilize uma `Column` com os widgets `Container` e `Text`.

Te aconselho criar um Widget separado pros itens, onde receba como parâmetro o texto e a imagem que deseja... Assim tu substitui todo o código do "Item 1" pelo widget criado, economizando assim linhas e deixando mais organizado.

```
   Widget _listOnline() {
        return ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Column( /* Item 1 */
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35),
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/Rubio_Circle.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("Nome aqui")
              ],
            ),
            Column( /* Item 2 */
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35),
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/Rubio_Circle.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("Nome aqui")
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, fiz como falou, criei outro widget e passei como parametros, mais facil de chamar também, obrigado

Comment: Postei mais uma pergunta que talvez vc consiga me ajudar, se puder claro